# How do you use grunt-generated minification maps?

Tags: bundling-and-minification, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using grunt to concat(grunt-concat) and minify ( grunt-uglify ) my JS files and I've found the option for source maps which I have enabled. This now generates minification maps for the concat process and the minification process.

My question is how do I use these to debug the page when it is deployed? Do I need to include them in the page script or load them into my browser manually? Do I need to point the minification map to the concat map in order to get meaningful code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have it configured correctly it should just work when you are debugging.

I have not been able to get visual studio to recognize the source mappings, but it does work in ie and chrome.